# mysql update query always return failed

Tags: php, html, mysql

My query always returns- echo "Menu update failed";. is there anything wrong in Update query? or something wrong in html form? (i know i should use mysqli but its just a experiment so i dont care it. please dont advice about mysqli)

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu");
echo '<form action="" method="post">'.'Desired Name:<input type="text" name="desname">'.'<select name="tobeupdate">'.'<br>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    $menu_name = $row['menu_name'];
    echo '<option value="'.$menu_name.'">'.$menu_name.'</option>';
}
echo '</select><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update now">
</form>';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $desname = $_POST['desname'];
    $tobeupdate = $_POST['tobeupdate'];
    if (empty($desname)) {
        echo "Enter your desired menu name";
    }
    else {
        $q2 ="UPDATE menu SET $desname WHERE menu_name=$tobeupdate";
    if (mysql_query($q2)) {
      echo "Menu update success!";
    }
    else {
      echo "Menu update failed";
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: $q2 ="UPDATE menu SET $desname WHERE menu_name=$tobeupdate", set desname to ?

Comment: You can use mysql_error() to find out exact error

Comment: You didn't specify the column you want to update. Your `UPDATE` query should be like this: `$q2 ="UPDATE menu SET your_column = '$desname' WHERE ...`

Comment: Use `mysqli` instead of deprecated `mysql` extension (removed in PHP 7)! http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Downvoted, this is extremely bad code full of SQL injection errors, please forget about `mysql_` and start using pdo.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Answer (score -1):

No quotation or double quotation marks around your $tobeupdated variable.
$tobeupdated="'".$tobeupdated."'";

Also specify what to set desname to

Comment: You don't quotes with variables in a `PHP` string http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: the quotes were for a string variable that was going to be passed into mysql, that requires quotes http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: That's right, but `$q2 ="UPDATE menu SET $desname WHERE menu_name='$tobeupdate'";` is enough "quoted", what I want to explain (not quite clear I have to admit). Clearify your answer and format the code part to be better readable.

Comment: The point is put quotes around a string you are passing into mysql